# Diagonalisation of sub-matrix of upper triangular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization, triangularization

Let's assume we have an upper triangular matrix $A \equiv (A_{i j}) \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ for which we know a diagonalisation $A = \Omega D \Omega^{-1}$.

If we now choose some index subsequence $(i_k)_{k=1, \ldots, n'}$, and delete all rows and columns whose indices are not contained in the subsequence, we obtain a sub-matrix $A' \in \mathbb{R}^{n' \times n'}$.

How can we get a diagonalisation of $A' = \Omega' D' \Omega'^{-1}$, $\Omega' \in \mathbb{R}^{n'\times n'}$ from the existing diagonalisation of $A$?

If need be, we can additionally make the following assumptions (though I doubt that they help much): $A$ has

- non-negative off-diagonal entries,
- non-positive diagonal entries
- and a last row that consists only of zeros.

I have wondered about this for a bit because initially it seemed like the problem should be trivial, but I haven't actually been able to come to a conclusion. Simply sub-indexing $\Omega$, $D$, and $\Omega^{-1}$ was the obvious idea, but I don't see how to actually do it.

Edit: For clarification, this is about a genuine diagonalisation with some square change of basis $\Omega'$, *not* just a product of a rectangular, diagonal, rectangular.

For an illustration as requested by @Will Jagy, we can consider a $3\times 3$ matrix
\begin{equation}
A = \begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
0 & a_{22} & a_{23} \\
0 & 0 & a_{33}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
which we can diagonalise as
\begin{equation}
\Omega^{-1} A \Omega = \begin{pmatrix}
\lambda_1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \lambda_2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \lambda_3
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation} for some $\Omega \in \mathbb{R}^{3 \times 3}$.
Now, we would like to use this information to obtain $\Omega' \in \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$ such that it provides a diagonalisation of the upper left $2 \times 2$ sub_matrix of $A$:

\begin{equation}
\Omega'^{-1} \begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} \\
0 & a_{22} \\
\end{pmatrix} \Omega' = \begin{pmatrix}
\lambda'_1 & 0 \\
0 & \lambda'_2 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

presumably with different eigenvalues $\lambda'_1, \lambda'_2$.

Comment: @WillJagy I'm not sure what you're referring to - in a $2\times 2$ system, we can't have a non-trivial sub-matrix, whereas for $3\times 3$ I already don't see a simple answer

Comment: @WillJagy I've tried to add a small example, I hope this makes it clearer.

Comment: I put an example (just output from gp-Pari). For distinct diagonal elements, you may just truncate  the first $k$  eigenvectors to get eigenvectors  for the upper left $k$ by $k$ square.  See my second answer.

Answer (score 1):

The upper left idea helped.  Take 4 by 4
$$
M=
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr|rr}
1 & A  & B  & * &* \\
0&1 & C & * &* \\ 
0&0&1 & * & *  \\ \hline
0&0&0&2 & * \\
0&0&0&0&2 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
For eigenvalue $1$   we demand that $A-I$ be nice...

$$
M-I=
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr|rr}
0 & A  & B  & * &* \\
0&0 & C & * &* \\ 
0&0&0 & * & *  \\ \hline
0&0&0&1 & * \\
0&0&0&0&1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Next we try to row reduce  this, in particular by row operations we can erase the upper right rectangle

$$
(M-I)_1=
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr|rr}
0 & A  & B  & 0 &0 \\
0&0 & C & 0 &0 \\ 
0&0&0 & 0 & 0  \\ \hline
0&0&0&1 & * \\
0&0&0&0&1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
In fact, we can squash the final $*$  for

$$
(M-I)_2=
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr|rr}
0 & A  & B  & 0 &0 \\
0&0 & C & 0 &0 \\ 
0&0&0 & 0 & 0  \\ \hline
0&0&0&1 & 0 \\
0&0&0&0&1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

When do we have three independent null vectors for this? Only when $A=B=C $  So we actually had this from the beginning:

$$
M=
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr|rr}
1 & 0  & 0  & * &* \\
0&1 & 0 & * &* \\ 
0&0&1 & * & *  \\ \hline
0&0&0&2 & * \\
0&0&0&0&2 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Comment: Could you clarify why we're assuming all eigenvalues within a block to be equal? (After all, in the example in the question, we already know that the eigenvalues are the $a_{kk}$, but those are typically distinct)

Comment: @MarcVaisband I was worried about repeats. Meanwhile, with your distinct eigenvalues, it seems the eigenvectors for an upper left square can be pure truncations of the full length eigenvalues. Please do some 3 by 3 and 4 by 4 examples with actual numbers, integers to simplify the appearance.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, from what I can see the eigenvectors for an upper left square can simply be **truncations** of the eigenvectors for the full size matrix.

Not so good when the chosen rows/columns fail to be contiguous. Still:

Example:

```
? m =  [ 1,5,9,13;  0,2,6, 10;  0,0,3,12; 0,0,0,4]
%2 = 
[1 5 9 13]

[0 2 6 10]

[0 0 3 12]

[0 0 0  4]

? mateigen(m)
%3 = 
[1 5 39/2 326/3]

[0 1    6    41]

[0 0    1    12]

[0 0    0     1]
-------------------------------------------------
? m3 = [ 1,5,9; 0,2,6; 0,0,3]
%4 = 
[1 5 9]

[0 2 6]

[0 0 3]

? mateigen(m3)
%5 = 
[1 5 39/2]

[0 1    6]

[0 0    1]

?
```

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
? m2 = [ 2,6; 0,3]
%9 = 
[2 6]

[0 3]

? mateigen(m2)
%10 = 
[1 6]

[0 1]

? mateigen(m)
%11 = 
[1 5 39/2 326/3]

[0 1    6    41]

[0 0    1    12]

[0 0    0     1]
```